# Какой метод открытия картинок практичнее в aiogram?

Tags: python, aiogram

```
photo = open("files\screen.png", "rb")
```

Или

```
with open("files\screen.png", "rb") as file:
    photo = file.read()
```

Возможно даже есть лучше и правильнее вариант открытия картинок?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Этот

```
from aiogram.types import InputFile 
photo = InputFile("pathtoimg.ext")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
photo = open("files\screen.png", "rb")
```

требует закрытия

```
photo.close()
```